# Match regex with any word in between 2 specific words

Tags: regex

I want to use regex in atom editor look for terms such as "**export data as**" or "**export contract as**". Pretty much "export ____ as" is the pattern so this is what I have:

**`/^(export)" "[a-z]*" "(as)$/`**

But it's not working when I tested it in my javascript console.

Answer (score 2):

If you literally want to match "export data as" and not " export data as " then you should use `/export [a-zA-Z]+ as/` otherwise you should use `/ export [a-zA-Z]+ as /` or if you also want to match strings such as "EXPORT DATA AS" just add an `i` to the end so: `/export [a-zA-Z]+ as/i` or if you are using javascript, as you added to your post, then you would want: `var regex = new RegExp("export [a-zA-Z]+ as", "i");`

If this doesn't answer your question then you should probably try regexes using http://regexr.com/ or look up the rules for regex on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant this:

```
/\\bexport [a-z]+ as\\b/
```

ie remove the quotes and brackets, and you probably want at least one char in the middle ie `+` rather than `*` as the quantifier, and wrapped in word boundaries `\b`.

Comment: The trailing `$` is almost certainly not what the poster wants; the leading `^` probably not, either. `\b`matching a word boundary makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try this

***`/(export|EXPORT)\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s([aA][sS])/`***

***[Working Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/P7Uxnx/3)***

> [image]
>
> [image]